# Why some object names starts with single or multiple underscores in c++?

Tags: c++, naming-conventions, naming

I've seen a lot of times in c++ libraries tones of objects whose names start with underscores. 
I know some cases when this is useful for example:

```
    class Person {
    private: 
       unsigned int age;
       //...
    public:
       Person(unsigned int _age): age(_age) {}
    };
```

here it's useful to distinguish logically same objects `_age`, `age`.

But there are also cases when global functions names (not from a class) also have single or multiple underscores. So I would like to understand this in general and more ideologically.

So:

**What are the benefits for this kind of naming ?**

**When it's need to use single and when multiple underscores at the start ?**

Comment: Double underscores are usually reserved for compiler's internal use as a convention. Single underscores are reserved for library functions to prevent collisions.

Comment: In this specific case, `Person(unsigned int age):age(age){}` would be legal as well (and produce the same code).

Comment: @ParagAgarwal - double underscores are **always** reserved, not sometimes.

Answer (score 0):

There's never a requirement to use an initial single or a double-underline prefix to variable names.

This is simply someone's naming convention, or a habit.

Comment: But there is a requirement not to use them per the standard.

Comment: Only certain types; namely an underscore followed by an uppercase letter.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik: Also double underscores.

Comment: And all double underscores and underscores in the global namespace.